# Why isnt the Main running?

Tags: c#, methods, static, program-entry-point, void

what have I done wrong to not get this to work?
The program is not done but I need to know what im doing wrong with the "static void main"
I´ve looked at this for several hours trying to find whats wrong at google and so, but I really cant understand. Probably the whole code is wrong but I just want answer for the main issue the rest I will look at later.

the Main is not running: [here is a picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4YUm.jpg)

[another one for more of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US66U.jpg)
[another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lengD.jpg)

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] ämnen = { "Matematik", "Svenska", "Engelska", "Historia", "Fysik" };
    int[] poäng = new int[5];
    char[] betyg = new char[6];
    Laspoang(ämnen, poäng);
    Af(ämnen, poäng, betyg);
    SkrivUtBetyg(ämnen, poäng, betyg);

    
    bool avsluta = false;
    while (!avsluta)

        Console.Write("[A]skriv betyg i A-F\n");
        Console.Write("[B]statistik\n");
        Console.Write("[C]skriv ut betyg\n");
        Console.Write("[D]avsluta\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\nDitt val: ");

        char menyVal;

        menyVal = Console.ReadLine()[0];

    switch (menyVal)

    {

        case 'a':
        case 'A':

            Af(ämnen, poäng, betyg);

            break;



        case 'b':
        case 'B':

            stat(ämnen, poäng, betyg);
            break;

        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            //ej klar

            break;

        case 'd':
        case 'D':

            Console.WriteLine("Hejdå");

            avsluta = true;

            break;

    }   }        
    static void Laspoang(string[] ämnen, int[] poäng)
    {
        int poängen;
        for (int i = 0; i < ämnen.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mata in poängen mellan 0-100 för " + ämnen[i] + ": ");
            poängen = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            poäng[i] = poängen;
        }
    }
    static void Af(string[] ämnen, int[] poäng, char[] betyg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ämnen.Length; i++)
        {
            if (poäng[i] > 90 && poäng[i] <= 100)
                betyg[i] = 'A';
            else if (poäng[i] > 80)
                betyg[i] = 'B';
            else if (poäng[i] > 70)
                betyg[i] = 'C';
            else if (poäng[i] > 60)
                betyg[i] = 'D';
            else if (poäng[i] >= 50)
                betyg[i] = 'E';
            else if (poäng[i] >= 0)
                betyg[i] = 'F';
            else
                betyg[i] = '!';
            Console.WriteLine(ämnen[i] + "= " + betyg[i]);
        }
    }
    static void stat(string[] ämnen, int[] poäng, char[] betyg)
    {
        int betyga = 0;
        int betygb = 0;
        int betygc = 0;
        int betygd = 0;
        int betyge = 0;
        int betygf = 0;
        int poängtot = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < poäng.Length; i++)
        {
            if (poäng[i] > 90 && poäng[i] <= 100)
                betyga++;
            else if (poäng[i] > 80)
                betygb++;
            else if (poäng[i] > 70)
                betygc++;
            else if (poäng[i] > 60)
                betygd++;
            else if (poäng[i] >= 50)
                betyge++;
            else if (poäng[i] >= 0)
                betygf++;
            else
                betyg[i] = '!';

        }
        Console.WriteLine("antal A: " + betyga);
        Console.WriteLine("antal B: " + betygb);
        Console.WriteLine("antal C: " + betygc);
        Console.WriteLine("antal D: " + betygd);
        Console.WriteLine("antal E: " + betyge);
        Console.WriteLine("antal F: " + betygf);

        for (int i = 0; i < poäng.Length; i++)
        {
            poängtot = poängtot + poäng[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("totala poäng: " + poängtot);
    }
    static void SkrivUtBetyg(string[] ämnen, int[] poäng, char[] betyg)
{

}
```

Comment: Hi @minmini, Welceome to StackOverFlow. There are plenty here that wants to help you. In order to do that, please supply the code you are having problems with. That way, we are all on the same page, and it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: I cant even write down the code in my post I´ve tried so many times but cant get it right, hopefully  its possible to see the problem at the picture sorry for that....

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements#no-other-entry-points

Comment: Put your code in a `Program` class. Example: `public class Program { /* your code here */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you need to have  it inside a  `Program` tag.

Have this a go

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] ämnen = {"Matematik", "Svenska", "Engelska", "Historia", "Fysik"};
        int[] poäng = new int[5];
        char[] betyg = new char[6];
        Laspoang(ämnen, poäng);
        Af(ämnen, poäng, betyg);
        SkrivUtBetyg(ämnen, poäng, betyg);
        bool avsluta = false;
        while (!avsluta)
            Console.Write("[A]skriv betyg i A-F\n");
        Console.Write("[B]statistik\n");
        Console.Write("[C]skriv ut betyg\n");
        Console.Write("[D]avsluta\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\nDitt val: ");
        char menyVal;
        menyVal = Console.ReadLine()[0];
        switch (menyVal)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                Af(ämnen, poäng, betyg);
                break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                stat(ämnen, poäng, betyg);
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                //ej klar
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                Console.WriteLine("Hejdå");
                avsluta = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    static void Laspoang(string[] ämnen, int[] poäng)
    {
        int poängen;
        for (int i = 0; i < ämnen.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mata in poängen mellan 0-100 för " + ämnen[i] + ": ");
            poängen = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            poäng[i] = poängen;
        }
    }

    static void Af(string[] ämnen, int[] poäng, char[] betyg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ämnen.Length; i++)
        {
            if (poäng[i] > 90 && poäng[i] <= 100)
                betyg[i] = 'A';
            else if (poäng[i] > 80)
                betyg[i] = 'B';
            else if (poäng[i] > 70)
                betyg[i] = 'C';
            else if (poäng[i] > 60)
                betyg[i] = 'D';
            else if (poäng[i] >= 50)
                betyg[i] = 'E';
            else if (poäng[i] >= 0)
                betyg[i] = 'F';
            else
                betyg[i] = '!';
            Console.WriteLine(ämnen[i] + "= " + betyg[i]);
        }
    }

    static void stat(string[] ämnen, int[] poäng, char[] betyg)
    {
        int betyga = 0;
        int betygb = 0;
        int betygc = 0;
        int betygd = 0;
        int betyge = 0;
        int betygf = 0;
        int poängtot = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < poäng.Length; i++)
        {
            if (poäng[i] > 90 && poäng[i] <= 100)
                betyga++;
            else if (poäng[i] > 80)
                betygb++;
            else if (poäng[i] > 70)
                betygc++;
            else if (poäng[i] > 60)
                betygd++;
            else if (poäng[i] >= 50)
                betyge++;
            else if (poäng[i] >= 0)
                betygf++;
            else
                betyg[i] = '!';
        }

        Console.WriteLine("antal A: " + betyga);
        Console.WriteLine("antal B: " + betygb);
        Console.WriteLine("antal C: " + betygc);
        Console.WriteLine("antal D: " + betygd);
        Console.WriteLine("antal E: " + betyge);
        Console.WriteLine("antal F: " + betygf);
        for (int i = 0; i < poäng.Length; i++)
        {
            poängtot = poängtot + poäng[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine("totala poäng: " + poängtot);
    }

    static void SkrivUtBetyg(string[] ämnen, int[] poäng, char[] betyg)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `public` in main method (for `public static void Main(string[] args)`) is not mandatory. ;)

Comment: This is not accurate - the `Main` method does *not* have to be `public` (and neither does its containing `class`).

Comment: It does depends on the compiler? If the compiler/framework if  4.5.6 then it needs to have `public` latest .net core then, no it is not needed. true

Comment: Try running the same code with and without public in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

Comment: What Rufus L said has been true since the very first release of .NET. It hasn't changed between compiler or runtime versions, or anything like that.

Comment: Okay, i did not know that. I’ll fix accordingly